# Customize serialized tabs php ClinicCases

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have this serialized tabs on my _tabs field on phpmyadmin

```
', 'a:8:{i:0;s:4:"Home";i:1;s:5:"Cases";i:2;s:5:"Group";i:3;s:5:"Users";i:4;s:8:"Journals";i:5;s:5:"Board";i:6;s:9:"Utilities";i:7;s:8:"Messages";}', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
```

and i have the follow tabs.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOAoU.jpg)

```
<?php

function tabs($dbh,$current)
{

    //Format the current tab by removing the php extension
    $current_tab = substr($current,0,-4);

    //Determine which tabs the user sees depending on their group membership
    $get_tab_config = $dbh->prepare('SELECT group_name,allowed_tabs FROM cm_groups WHERE group_name = ? ');

    $get_tab_config->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['group']);
    $get_tab_config->execute();
    $r = $get_tab_config->fetch();

    $group_tabs = unserialize($r['allowed_tabs']);

    //output the tabs
    ob_start();
    echo "<div id='tabs'><ul>";

    foreach ($group_tabs as $tab) {
        if ($tab == $current_tab) {
            echo "<li class='current' id = 'tab_$tab'><a href='index.php?i=" . $tab . ".php'><span>$tab</span></a></li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li><a id = 'tab_$tab' href='index.php?i=" . $tab . ".php'><span>$tab</span></a></li>";
        }
    }

    echo "</ul></div>";
    $tabs_html = ob_get_clean();

    return $tabs_html;
}
```

how can i edit the tabs name?

I have tryed to edit it from the db but after doing this all the menu disappear

Comment: WHat are your tabs called currently

Comment: Home - Cases - Users - Board - Utilities - Messagges
 i am using ClinicCases 7 ( try to follow their guide) but they dont show how to create new tab https://cliniccases.com/documentation/#!customization.md

Comment: i have solved by changed the name of tabs by an array:
After a  bit of time, if you want to change the name of the tabs you just need to copy and paste this code to tabs.php file inside the software:
`<?php

`   //Array for change the name of tab    $tab_names = array(
        "Tab1" => "Nuovo nome1",
        "Tab2" => "Nuovo nome2",
        "Tab3" => "Nuovo nome3"
    );`

Comment: _"I have tryed to edit it from the db but after doing this all the menu disappear"_ - the `serialize` format contains the type and length of the values - so if you were to change any string value, it would either have to be with a value of the exact same length, or you would need to modify the length indicator as well. If the two don't match, then the attempt to unserialize this data will simply fail. Manipulating data like this manually should be avoided; if anything, you should unserialize it, modify the resulting data structure, and then serialize it again.